# strange message from gradle (AndroidStudio).

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

From one second to the other I got the following error with **Gradle** in **AndroidStudio** and I have no clue what to do with it.

Error when trying to start my app:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_map_testApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.0.0
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.0.0 > com.android.support:transition:25.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.0.0 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.0.0 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
```

build.gradle : (Mobile: app) (Did not changed since month. Compared with repo and no change)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        sapps {
            keyAlias 'keyalias'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxx'
            storeFile file('C:/eclipse/keystore/mykeystore')
            storePassword 'xxxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 179
        versionName "2.54"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "appID", "wgd"
        manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon", versionCode:"161", versionName:"2.37"]

    }
    buildTypes {
        demo {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WGD\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Chronica"
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_demo"]
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser'
        }
        demo_test {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WGD_TEST\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
            debuggable true

            resValue "string", "app_name", "Chronica Test"
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_demo"]
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_wgd_test'
        }
        timeline {

            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WG\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldHistory"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_wg_en'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_timeline", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_timeline"]
        }
        timeline_test {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WG_TEST\""
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldHistory Test"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_wg_en'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_timeline_test", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_timeline"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
        }
        map {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WG_MAPS\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldHistory Atlas"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_maps_en'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_maps", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_maps"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
        }
        map_test {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WG_MAPS_TEST\""
            //resValue "string", "RES_appID", "wgd"
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldHistory Atlas Test"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_maps_en'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_maps_test", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_maps"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps

        }
        worldwarII {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WW2\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldWar II"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_ww2_en'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_ww2", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_ww2"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps

        }
        worldwarII_test {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"WW2_TEST\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "WorldWar II Test"
            applicationIdSuffix '.chronicbrowser_ww2_en_test'
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon_ww2", facebookid:"@string/facebook_app_id_ww2"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sapps
        }
    }
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/lvl.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: what is so strange ... newest facebook sdk require support library 27.0.1

Comment: When adding 27.0.1 I get the same issue. The problem seems to be not only facebook, but in general ?

Comment: becuase it is no longer in local maven repo ... asked multiple times

Comment: ok understood now. Thanks I try with google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent versions of the Android libraries are available from Google's Maven repository.

To include Google's Maven repository:

in your **top-level** `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Details:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: Thanks. I installed the newest AndroidStudio, Gradle Plugin and added google() as new Repo and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due of `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`. Change it with

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') { 
         exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

it is the only one that has an *open* version.

Comment: I tried, but I get lots of other errors like resources not found.

Comment: upvoted yours, because you gave me the correct hint regarding facebook version, which made the hole mess. I fixed the version now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lower version of the support library than the one required by the other components. try

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
```

Comment: I changed all to 27.0.1 -> Target SDK=27 , buildToolsVersion "27.0.1", your two lines too. Still the same issue